# Running '/usr/libexec/java_home -V' shows path that does not exist

Tags: java, macos, java-16

When I run `/usr/libexec/java_home -V` on MacOS I get the following output:

```
Matching Java Virtual Machines (1):
    16.0.2 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "OpenJDK 16.0.2" /Users/dummy/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-16.0.2/Contents/Home
/Users/dummy/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-16.0.2/Contents/Home
```

However, when I navigate to the JavaVirtualMachines directory and run `ls -a` there is no /openjdk-16.0.2 directory. Why is this? I am trying to uninstall OpenJDK 16 and get rid of all traces of it from my computer.

Comment: The title and the question do not agree. The title says, ***"Running '/usr/libexec/java_home -V' shows path that does not exist"***. The body says, ***"When I run /usr/libexec/java_home -V on MacOS I get the following output:

Matching Java Virtual Machines (1):..."***.

Comment: @Arvind OP is saying the folder shown doesn't exist on disk

Comment: how did you install JDK-16? any package that might have symlinked it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.